# Can't resart liquidsoap without killing process manually

Tags: linux, port, ubuntu-14.04, icecast, liquidsoap

I am currently running Liquidsoap on Ubuntu 14.4, streaming to Icecast, hosted on the same box.

My setup is running correctly, however when running sudo service liquidsoap restart, I get the following error:

```
fatal error exception unix.unix_error(50, "bind", "" )
```

In order to restart liquid soap, I need to kill the process or reboot.

It then runs correctly. Until I need to restart for whatever reason.

As a side note, liquidsoap created a user and group called liquidsoap, however I am running sudo commands via another user I created.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What init.d script are you using?  I have a similar problem, and I assume it's because the init.d script can't find the PID file.

Comment: aaaah I have a line in the script that prevents a pid file being created.

I'll take a look and come back to you! Thanks!

Comment: You sir are a genius. It was due to a missing pid. Thank you!

Comment: No problem.  Can you post your init.d file as an answer?

Comment: Yep - should be done now

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by enabling pid file creation.

Copy of my init.d - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d7e232fc280d2fe1df56

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          liquidsoap
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network $time
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network $time
# Should-Start:
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts the liquidsoap daemon
# Description:
### END INIT INFO

user=liquidsoap
group=liquidsoap
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
confdir=/etc/liquidsoap
liquidsoap=${exec_prefix}/bin/liquidsoap
rundir=/var/run/liquidsoap

# Test if $rundir exists
if [ ! -d $rundir ]; then
  mkdir -p $rundir;
  chown $user:$group $rundir
fi

case "$1" in
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping liquidsoap channels: "
    cd $rundir
    has_channels=
    for liq in *.pid ; do
      if test $liq != '*.pid' ; then
        has_channels=1
        echo -n "$liq "
        start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $liq --retry 4
      fi
    done
    if test -n "$has_channels"; then
      echo "OK"
    else
      echo "no script found in $confdir"
    fi
    ;;

  start)
    echo -n "Starting liquidsoap channels: "
    cd $confdir
    has_channels=
    for liq in *.liq ; do
      if test $liq != '*.liq' ; then
        has_channels=1
        echo -n "$liq "
        start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $rundir/${liq%.liq}.pid \
          --chuid $user:$group --exec $liquidsoap -- -d $confdir/$liq
      fi
    done
    if test -n "$has_channels"; then
      echo "OK"
    else
      echo "no script found in $confdir"
    fi
    ;;

  restart|force-reload)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|force-reload}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: I finally got around to addressing this problem on my own systems.  I wasn't able to use this script on its own, but it did work fine once I added the following to the top of my Liquidsoap script:  `set("init.daemon.pidfile.path","/var/run/liquidsoap/main.pid")`  It seems the process ID of Liquidsoap changes once it gets running, so `--make-pidfile` with `start-stop-daemon` wasn't appropriate in this scenario.  Anyway, I hope that's helpful to someone else!

Answer (score 0):

None of mentioned solutions solved my issue. I had to fix it recently by setting proper ownership and permissions right after starting daemons. After killing the processes and restarting, further restarts work fine.

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $rundir/${liq%.liq}.pid \
  --chuid $user:$group --exec $liquidsoap -- -d $confdir/$liq  && sleep 1 && chmod 600 $rundir/${liq%.liq}.pid && chown root:root $rundir/${liq%.liq}.pid
```